# Cron expression at 11h30 and 19h every day

Tags: cron, scheduling

I would like to make a cron expression that runs at 11:30 a.m. and 7 p.m. every day.
But `0 30 11,19 ? * * *` runs at 11h30 and 19h30
And `0 30,0 11,19 ? * * *` runs at 11h, 11h30, 19h and 19h30
How can I write the cron expression to do what I want ?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Just add two lines:

```
30 11 * * * some-command
0  19 * * * some-command
```

To factorise the code to avoid having to repeat it, you could store it in an environment variable:

```
CODE = some sh code here
30 11 * * * eval "$CODE"
0  19 * * * eval "$CODE"
```

Or even:

```
CODE = some sh code here
RUN = eval eval "$CODE"
30 11 * * * $RUN
0  19 * * * $RUN
```